# How to define an Object based on Angular Form onSubmit()

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-httpclient

In my Angular app, I am able to send a PUT request that updates a JSON file successfully.

Now, I am trying to send a POST request to add another object to this JSON file.

I click an 'Edit' button & that populates some input fields with an existing record. I then make changes & click 'Save' to update the JSON successfully.

Now, when I don't click the 'Edit' button, & just enter some new data, & click 'Save', I get the following error:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'fullName' of undefined

HTML Form:

```
<form [formGroup]="signUpForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary [disabled]="signUpForm.invalid">
Save
</button>
</form>
```

Here is some of my Typescript:

```
signUpForm: FormGroup;
employee: IEmployee;

ngOnInit() {

    this.signUpForm = this.fb.group({
      fullName: [''],
      contactPreference: [''],
      emailGroup: this.fb.group({
        email: [''],
        confirmEmail: [],
      }),
      phone: [''],
      skills: this.fb.array([
        this.addSkillFormGroup()
      ])
    });
}

onSubmit(): void {
    this.mapFormValuesToEmployeeModel();

    if (this.employee.id) {
        this._employeeService.updateEmployee(this.employee).subscribe(
          () => this.loadExistingEmployees(),
          (err) => console.log(err)
        );
     } else {
    console.log('TODO: Add POST functionality here');
    }
}

mapFormValuesToEmployeeModel() {
    this.employee.fullName = this.signUpForm.value.fullName;
    this.employee.contactPreference = this.signUpForm.value.contactPreference;
    this.employee.email = this.signUpForm.value.emailGroup.email;
    this.employee.phone = this.signUpForm.value.phone;
    this.employee.skills = this.signUpForm.value.skills;
}
```

The code is crashing when it hits the first line of the `mapFormValuesToEmployeeModel()` method.

Here is the Employee Interface:

```
export interface IEmployee {
  id: number;
  fullName: string;
  email: string;
  phone?: number;
  contactPreference: string;
  skills: ISkill[];
}
```

Can someone please tell me what changes I need to make in order to get POST working?

I think the issue is that I need to assign the ID of the `employee` object somewhere, but I'm not sure exactly where to do this.

Comment: I assume that error occurred in the `mapFormValuesToEmployeeModel()` method?

Comment: @wentjun Hi, yes. That error is displayed on the first line of that method

Comment: @lealceldeiro Hi, the values in `signUpForm` contain the data that I want to assign to the `employee` object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to initialize the `employee` object before using it. Maybe like this:

```
// these should be some default values, they will be replaced later
employee: IEmployee = { id: -1, fullName: '', email: '', contactPreference: '', skills: []};
```

or

```
employee: IEmployee = { } as IEmployee;
```

Then you can use it inside the `mapFormValuesToEmployeeModel` method.

Side note: If you're trying to bind the values in the form to the `employee` variable, you might want to use the [NgModel](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel) directive for this purpose.

Comment: just initialize employee as `employee:IEmploye={}` make the trick

Comment: @Eliseo yeah, that could work too definitely. I posted it like that because you [could get an annoying compile error](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-initialization-example?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts) if you don't provide all the required parameters defined in the interface.

Comment: you're rigth, what about:, `employee1: IEmployee = { } as IEmployee` ?

Comment: @Eliseo Yup, that did it ;) Thanks!